# "Gem bundler is not installed" in Capistrano deployment - Error message UPDATED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm, capistrano

Here is the error caused by rake in Capistrano deployment. The error also causes the rollback and failure of the rails 3.1.3 deployment (with rvm for single user installed).

```
 ** [out :: 76.195.225.93] ←[31mERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem in
    command finished in 54ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/byop/releases/20120302230229; true"
```

`gem list` shows bundler 1.0.22. Also bundler was added to default.gems and global.gems under .rvm/gemset/. What could cause the error? Thanks so much.

Comment: Does the precompile task work for you locally?

Comment: ran rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile locally. almost 3 minutes passed, it is still running. But it seems OK.

Comment: very slow. May take 5 min. but it worked without error.

Comment: Is this your first attempt at deploying this app or was it already deploying correctly for previous versions of Rails? Post your `deploy.rb` file too.

Comment: first attempt for the new server.

Comment: Post your `deploy.rb` file or the full output of your deploy attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install bundler in the server gemset.

Comment: ran gem install bundler again. The error for deployment is the same.

Comment: added bundler to default.gems and global.gems on server under gemset. Still could not find bundler. Any place that I could missed?

Comment: Are you sure the user you're deploying as is using rvm?

Answer (score 1):

Set the default environment in deployment recipe:

```
set :default_environment, {
'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby-1.9.2-p320',
'LANG'         => 'en_US.UTF-8',
'GEM_HOME'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320',
'GEM_PATH'     => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global',
'BUNDLE_PATH'  => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global'
}
```

You can have just bundle path in your case!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Check and see if there is a file called `rvm.sh` in your `/etc/profile.d` directory. If so, then you installed `rvm` in *multiuser* mode. I fixed it on my server (Ubuntu 12.04) by adding `source /etc/profile` to my `.bashrc` file in my home directory on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bundler installed in an RVM gemset on the remote server, be sure to:

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
```

if your config/deploy.rb

If you get an error for that require, you might need to fix your rvm path as well in deploy.rb using:

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
```

I prefer that to just installing gems as system gems.  RVM is your friend.